# Shopping cart not working in opencart because someone disabled it from core

Tags: php, opencart

Some old employee disabled the shopping cart function in an opencart site.
I somehow find that the add to cart and quanitity button was commented out.

I placed the following code to show the add to cart button.

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="" onclick="addToCart(<?php echo $product_id;?>,parseInt($('#quantity').val()))" />
```

I placed the onclick event by myself as i figured out that there is an `addtoCart()` function.

Now I checked on the console that the function is running fine and its giving me alert of adding products. However in the top of the page where its written `Shoppingcart:item(0)`.

The shopping cart items are not increasing and even the hyperlink is not active. From which file i can correct this and what can be the problem?

Sorry if I could not describe my problem in detail as its the first time I'm working on opencart and don't know much about it.

Thanks

Updated:

I see here in header.tpl file that the

```
            <div class="cartSearch">
            <span><b>Shopping Cart:</b> item(0)</span>
            <span>
```

is hardcoded.

What should i place here?

Comment: As i'm also bignner in open cart, for such problem, i would reinstall opencart and link it to old database. easy solution. Unless Opencart is modified specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while there is no `<div class="cartSearch">` in default theme of opencart. but the cart you are looking is diplayed using

`<?php echo $cart; ?>`.

place this inside `<div id="header"> .. </div>` in `header.tpl`

you can download your respective version of your opencart from here http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download and compare the file(s) for changes

Comment: <?php echo $this->cart->countProducts(); ?>

That was the function i placed and it worked. Any ways to some extent your answer is right as its showing a small box of checkout.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have a **problem on the function addToCart** () of opencart when opening for fist time the website we have done the hack:

We have added an error function that goes to an specific url (the same of the link).

place= catalog/view/javascript/common.js

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {

    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
    dataType: 'json',
            error: function (){
                 ruta = "http://barcelonapakker.com/booking/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=" + product_id; 
                 window.location = ruta;
            },
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

        if (json['redirect']) {
            location = json['redirect'];
        }

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }   
    }

});
}
```